# How to Use NSCoder with Versioned Classes

Tags: ios, versioning, nscoder

I'm having a bit of a struggle with NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver when the properties of the object change between the archive and unarchive process. Here's a concrete example:

I have a class, let's say `Task`, and it has the attributes `name` and `desc`, both of type `NSString`. Now, I archive using `NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject` and write it to a file. I can later read it from a file and use `NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData(data)` to get right back where I want to be. The problem comes when `Task` acquires a new property and, to make things interesting, loses one.

So now, `Task` has `name`, which is an `NSString`, but `desc` is missing. Further, I add the property `dateDue` of type `NSDate`. And then fire up the simulator. The problem is that what's unarchived is the old `Task` with the old `desc` property but not the new `dateDue`.

My `initFromCoder` actually takes the case into account where a property is not present in the current class and doesn't attempt to decode it.

Is there a way to explain to the NSCoder methods not to create me an exact replica of the object as it was when I serialized it (I realized that is part of the definition of serialization/deserialization) but rather to allow me the flexibility to version it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple way - write the version to the data and read it as the beginning of `initFromCoder`. If the version comparison fails, just return `nil` from the initializer.

When you add a property, even if you attempt to decode the data, you just get a `nil` value. You can always check for `nil` values.

When you remove a property, there shouldn't be any problem.

Note that you are the one implementing both encoding and decoding, so you can implement it any way you want.